# Ruby transform string of range measurements into a list of the measurements?

Tags: ruby

I have a sample string that I would like to transform, from this:

```
#21inch-#25inch
```

to this:

```
#21inch #22inch #23inch #24inch #25inch
```

Using Ruby, please show me how this can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex gsub with a block match replacement, like this:

```
string = "#21inch-#25inch"
new_string = string.gsub(/#\d+\w+-#\d+\w+/) do |match|
  first_capture, last_capture = match.split("-")
  first_num = first_capture.gsub(/\D+/, "").to_i
  last_num = last_capture.gsub(/\D+/, "").to_i

  pattern = first_capture.split(/\d+/)
  (first_num..last_num).map {|num| pattern.join(num.to_s) }.join(" ")
end

puts "#{new_string}"
```

Running this will produce this output:

```
First: #21inch Last: #25inch
First num: 21 Last num: 25
Pattern: ["#", "inch"]
#21inch #22inch #23inch #24inch #25inch
```

The last line of output is the answer, and the previous lines show the progression of logic to get there.

This approach should work for other, slightly different unit formats, as well:

```
#32ft-#49ft
#1mm-5mm
#2acres-5acres
```

Making this suit multiple purposes will be quite simple.  With a slight variation in the regex, you could also support a range format `#21inch..#25inch`:

```
/(#\d+\w+)[-.]+(#\d+\w+)/
```

Happy parsing!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write  `first_capture, last_capture = "#21inch-#25inch".split('-')?

Comment: Thanks for your versatile solution, it works with other range formats, too. Very smart!!

Answer (score 6):

You can `scan` your string and working with range of strings:

```
numbers = "#21inch-#25inch".scan(/\d+/)
=> ["21", "25"]
Range.new(*numbers).map{ |s| "##{s}inch" }.join(" ")
=> "#21inch #22inch #23inch #24inch #25inch"
```

This solution working only if your string has a format like in your instance. For other cases you should write your own specific solution.

Comment: You could alternatively write `first, last = "#21inch..."; (first..last).map { |s|...}`.

Comment: Yes, it is alternative way to create `Range` objects. Thanks, @CarySwoveland. I think my solution is more readable, so I've left it)

Comment: thanks for your short and well maintainable solution, it works!

Answer (score 4):

```
R = /
    (\D*)     # match zero or more non-digits in capture group 1
    (\d+)     # match one or more digits in capture group 2
    ([^\d-]+) # match on or more chars other the digits and hyphens in capture group 3
    /x        # free-spacing regex definition mode

def spin_out(str)
  (prefix, first, units),(_, last, _) = str.scan(R)
  (first..last).map { |s| "%s%s%s" % [prefix,s,units] }.join(' ')
end

spin_out "#21inch-#25inch"
  #=> "#21inch #22inch #23inch #24inch #25inch" 
spin_out "#45cm-#53cm"
  #=> "#45cm #46cm #47cm #48cm #49cm #50cm #51cm #52cm #53cm" 
spin_out "sz 45cm-sz 53cm"
  #=> "sz 45cm sz 46cm sz 47cm sz 48cm sz 49cm sz 50cm sz 51cm sz 52cm sz 53cm" 
spin_out "45cm-53cm"
  #=> "45cm 46cm 47cm 48cm 49cm 50cm 51cm 52cm 53cm"
```

For `str = "#21inch-#25inch"`, we obtain

```
(prefix, first, units),(_, last, _) = str.scan(R)
  #=> [["#", "21", "inch"], ["-#", "25", "inch"]] 
prefix
  #=> "#" 
first
  #=> "21" 
units
  #=> "inch" 
last
  #=> "25"
```

The subsequent mapping is straightforward.

Comment: I love the elegance of your solution.  Superb!

Comment: I've learned a bit more about regex magic :-) Thanks for your well documentated regex and this gallant solution!